# Good Resources for Learning Modeling of fMRI Data

Tags: neuroscience, reference-request, computational-modeling, fmri

As a neuroscience student who works with fMRI I'm competent at the standard univariate analyses and resting state analysis techniques in AFNI and MATLAB/SPM. However, I want to learn how to use models in fMRI data analyses from a start-to-finish perspective.

More specifically, I want to learn how to model prediction error like they did in [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23278978) for example. The problem is, I have no one to teach/help me.

**What are recommended resources (online or textbooks), for learning modelling of fMRI data in detail?**

Comment: I think this question could be useful and on-topic if reworded to simply ask for resources to learn about models used in fMRI. As it stands the question is more about how to implement a model in software, which is off-topic.

Comment: This question is still primarily opinion-based.  The problem is that someone can recommend a book or 2 which **in their opinion** would help, but others may have the opinion that a couple of other books would be better

Comment: I believe it is a shame this question was closed. It asks for sources where one can learn about advanced modelling and analysis. The only opinionated thing is the word "good" and could have easily been edited.